# How to get the repositories on Bitbucket with most commits?

Tags: javascript, api, bitbucket

I am new to the Bitbucket and trying to retrieve the Javascript repositories with most commits.

I have looked over the API documentation. But it seems no solutions are found. How can I do that? An example would be better, thx!

Answer (score 0):

Bitbucket currently does not offer a global index, so if you mean you want to find the one repository, containing javascript, on all of Bitbucket, that contains more commits than any other repo, you're out of luck.